# Serialize Polars `dataframe` to `serde_json::Value`

Tags: json, rust, serialization, rust-polars

In Polars, it is simple enough to serialize a `DataFrame` to a json *string*: `JsonWriter::new(dest).finish(&df)?`.

Is it possible to serialize to a json *Value* — a `serde_json::Value` — that is the `Value::Array` of records? Obviously, I could write the json to an in-memory string, then deserialize it into a `serde_json::Value`. But I'm wondering if there is a direct path from `DataFrame` to `serde_json::Value`.

This would be the rough equivalent of pandas [`df.to_dict(orient="records")`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html).

Comment: Are you looking for [`serde_json::to_value()`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.94/serde_json/fn.to_value.html)?

Comment: @user2722968 That won't help, because `DataFrame` does not implement `Serialize`. AFAICT (from looking through polars' [`json::write`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/export/arrow/io/json/write/index.html) module), there's no direct way to convert `DataFrame` to `serde_json::Value` beyond serializing it to a byte buffer and then using `serde_json::from_slice` for conversion to `serde_json::Value`

Comment: @JonasFassbender I'm not familiar with Polars but afaics it does not support serde at all. If the object is small (and if you can live with the ugliness), serializing to a json-string and deserializing the string to a `serde_json::Value` seems to be the easiest way. Just don't tell anybody. The correct way would be to implement a `serialize_df() -> serde_json::Value` yourself using a custom [`Serializer`](https://serde.rs/impl-serialize.html) for whatever your `df` contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `serde` feature.

```bash
cargo add polars --features serde
```

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let df = df! {
        "a" => [1,2,3,4,5],
    }
    .unwrap();
    let df_json = serde_json::to_value(&df).unwrap();
    println!("df_json {df_json}");
}
```

Note, Polars implements a custom de/serialize, and it may not align with the pandas equivalent mentioned.

The JSON result from above:

```json
{
  "columns": [
    {
      "datatype": "Int32",
      "name": "a",
      "values": [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Close enough, thanks.